# Mutate rows of dataframe based on previous rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have three vectors, `coin.flips`, `alpha`, and `beta`.  Here they are initialized:

```
coin.flips <- c(NA,rbinom(n = 5, size = 1, prob = 0.5))

N <- length(coin.flips)

alpha <- rep(0,length(coin.flips))
alpha[1]<-1

beta <- rep(0,length(coin.flips))
beta[1]<-1
```

I would like to update `alpha`/`beta` depending on the value of `coin.flips`.  If `coin.flips==1` then increment `alpha`, else increment `beta`.  Here is how I do it in base R.

```
for(i in 2:N){
  if(coin.flips[i]>0){
    alpha[i] = alpha[i-1]+1
    beta[i] = beta[i-1]
  }
  else{
    alpha[i] = alpha[i-1]
    beta[i] = beta[i-1]+1
  }
}
```

How can I do this in a tidy way?  Suppose that `coin.flips` is a column of a tibble or data.frame.  Is there an easy way to construct new columns `alpha`/`beta` that increment depending on the value of `coin.flips` and the previous values of `alpha`/`beta`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take. Given you have a column called coin.flips in dataframe df:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(coin.flips = c(rbinom(n = N, size = 1, prob = 0.5)))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(alpha = 1 + cumsum(coin.flips),
         beta  = 1 + cumsum(if_else(coin.flips == 0, 1, 0))) %>% 
  print
```

Comment: Spectacular!  Thank you